# Gmail / Google apps for domains mail alias problem

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have a domain that we will call `mydomain.com`.

The mail was originally set up using Google apps for domains.  Somewhere along the way to go changed a couple things about Google apps for domains. Number one the name. Number two it's no longer free.

I have successfully set up the domain so that I can use my browser to go to:   `mail.mydomain.com`.

My problem comes in when I try to add a alias to the domain and use it successfully.  Lets call it `myalias.com`.

1. I can't seem to get Google to respond to: `mail.myalias.com`. I have tried both setting the DNS to `ghs.googe.com` and I have tried setting a CNAME to `mail.mydomain.com`.
2. On my iPhone I would like to have the mail come from `me@myalais.com`.  But I can't figure out how to configure the iPhone to do it.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

In your control panel, you need to add your alias to the Google Apps account to allow the receipt of email:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295?hl=en

Then in your DNS, you need to setup mail.youralias.com as a redirect to mail.yourdomain.com

You then setup you@youralias.com as a send-as for your you@yourdomain.com :

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Finally, you install the Gmail app on your phone. It will respect your send-as settings in your Google Apps account.